# Kafka: how to fix the issue of corrupt offsets, and how to manually reset the offset of consumer to read again?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

How to fix the issue of corrupt offsets, and how to manually reset the offset of consumer to read again?

I am not sure how to do it manually in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set position of the consumer manually by calling `KafkaConsumer.seek(TopicPartition partition, long offset`) method.

Comment: Thank you Katya, can you please tell how and where to store offsets in Production grade application? any sample code ?

Comment: We use default storage for offsets, we store them in Kafka.

Comment: You can take ideas from https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/06/offset-management-for-apache-kafka-with-apache-spark-streaming/